# converting rgb image to gray image in vc++ using opencv

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

i created gui application in vc++2010 express, i loaded image folder to list box and by selecting listbox item the image is displaying in picturebox1, using browse button.
Now i want to access the picturebox1 image and convert to gray scale image and converted grey scale must be displayed in picturebox2, using grey convert button. plzz help me frnds

thanq
karuna

Answer (score 6):

Get the image in opencv Mat. Then use cvtColor function to convert the image. CV_BGR2GRAY code  is used to convert from RGB to grayscale. Then show the grayscale image back to wherever you want to display it.